# checking checkbox and then input to a new row

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

How can i insert into the database based on a checkbox result.

I have 5 rooms available and a user can book more then 1.

How do i insert the data to my bookings table for the rooms selected only.

This is what i was trying but it would only work for the 1st room, did try elseif but this didnt work either.

```
    if(isset($_POST['room1'])) {
        $query = "insert into bookings (bookingNo,roomNo) 
        values ('$bookingNo','1')";                 
        $result = mysql_query($query);
    }
```

This is basicly just to input the roomNo and the details for that room, such as date booked and time.

Thanks

**Form**

```
            <fieldset>

            <legend>Rooms</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <label for =youthCafe>Youth Cafe</label>
                        <input type="checkbox"name="roomid[]" value="1" ><br>
                        <label for =inkwellMain>Inkwell Main</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="roomid[]" value="2"><br>
                        <label for =inkwellSmall>Inkwell Small</label>
                        <input type="checkbox"name="roomid[]" value="3"><br>
                        <label for =kitchen>Kitchen</label>
                        <input type="checkbox"name="roomid[]" value="4"><br>
                        <label for =outsideCatering>Outside Catering</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="roomid[]" value="5"><br>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
```

Comment: You must have checkbox name declared as array. By getting names as array, you can apply for/foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

You should create first your form. As you did not mentioned it I will post an example:

**Important:** You should use MYSQLi or PDO functions to avoid sql injection. Aside that this is what you will need. (just the basics)

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['roomid']) ){
    foreach( $_POST['roomid'] as $value ){ //Receive the checkboxes as an array

         //you did not specify where $bookingNo came from, so
         //I'm assuming that you already have it from somewhere.

         $query = "insert into bookings (bookingNo,roomNo) 
                    values ('$bookingNo','$value')"; 

         $result = mysql_query($query);
    }
}
?>

<html>

<body>
    <form name="frm" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="roomid[]" value="1"/>Room 1<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="roomid[]" value="2"/>Room 2<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="roomid[]" value="3"/>Room 3<br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/><br/>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah i got bookingNo from another table that stores the bookingNo and customerNo, thanks i will try and let you know if it works.

Comment: @FallingStar pay attention to the name of the checkbox on the HTML form `roomid[]` it is how php will understand `$_POST['roomid']` as an array

Comment: It is still not working, it will only write the 1st one to the database.

Comment: Can you show the result of `var_dump( $yourRoomVariable );` ?

Comment: I mean the equivalent variable for: `$_POST['roomid']`

Comment: The output was - string(1) "2"

Comment: So it means that your checkbox is either with different names like `<input type='checkbox' name='romm1[]'> ... <input type='checkbox' name='romm2[]'>`, does not have the `[]` on it names or you just choose one option on the form.

Comment: @Jorge I have added to my question so you can see the form.

Comment: Are you sure you put the var_dump outside of the FOR command ? And you  marked more than one option right ?

Comment: @jorge yeah i marked more then 1 option for sure. this is the latest var_dump array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "5"

Comment: Are there any javascript code that might be messing up with your `roomid[]` form variable?! The code is pretty straightforward there is nothing to change and I even test your code on my side and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

if room1 is the checkbox.
Probably the $_POST['room1'] is set with "on" and not on "true" or "1".
Debug $_POST['room1'] first

```
var_dump($_POST['room1']);
```

Most times this helps to find out more about type and setted value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to set an event on the checkbox that calls an ajax function on the server.    The function on the server updates the database.  This way you separate the database work from the interface work.  With JQuery it would look like:

```
$('#myformelement :checkbox').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
        "url":      (call function using http request)...,
        "type":     "post",
        "data":     { elementid },
        "success":  function(data) {
            //everything ok
        },
        "error": function(data) {
           //error
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="room[]" value="1" />PHP<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="room[]" value="2" />HTML<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="room[]" value="3" />Java<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="room[]" value="4" />C++<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="room[]" value="5" />C++<br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
if ( isset($_POST['room']) ){
    foreach($_POST['room'] as $value)
    {
        $query = "insert into bookings (bookingNo,roomNo) 
            values ('$bookingNo','$value')";                 
            $result = mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works for 1 box, I need it to allow multiple boxes to be checked and insert a new row for each of them. For example if room 1 and 2 are checks it will insert bookingno x room 1 and then bookingno x and room 2 on seprate lines.

Comment: it will work for all checkboxes which are checked.. For ex. if form is submitted by checking 3 checkboxes,then foreach loop will execute 3 times and hence 3 insert queries will be executed. Try it